# Compiled and installed Python manually - is it installed correctly?

Tags: python

I downloaded, compiled and installed Python 3 directly from [python.org](https://www.python.org/) on MacOS 10.14 (Mojave). I had a few errors when installing, but showing `.configure` where the missing requirements are appeared to solve that.

However - `pip` wasn't included/installed when I would have expected it to be. Should I try and re-install or just install `pip` separately?

Comment: `python -mpip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: I wouldn't bother compiling and installing it myself on Mac OS. Homebrew is an awful lot less bother to get the same result.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: If pip hasn't been bootstrapped, wouldn't you need something like `python -m ensurepip`? I don't think you can use pip to install pip if you don't have pip.